# Qnap won't connect to Windows Share

Tags: network-shares, home-networking, htpc, video-streaming, connection

I have a qnap nmp-1000 in my network and would like to stream my films from my win7 laptop to the nmap-1000 device.

I just managed to do so with upnp sharing, but I would like to, for security reasons, share my files over a shared folder which is password protected.

My problem is when I'm searching for devices on my network with the qnap then it won't find any. When I try to mount a remote disk on my qnap it will just fail with an connection failed message. But when I try to connect to the qnap device with my laptop, it does this succesfully.

Can someone guide me through on how to get my setup working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that sharing is enabled on Windows 7. [HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/share-files-and-printers-between-windows-7-and-xp/) has a how-to.

Then check that you've set the security correctly on the share and the folder itself.

You may need to fiddle in the LAN Manager Authentication Level in your Local Security Policy. Check out [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itpronetworking/thread/68ffbe2a-09a7-4e29-859c-ca1aaf75dcd1) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. My folders are shared, and it is also enabled on my computer. Once, just by luck, it found a computer and got into the files. Then, the next day, it failed. I don't know if it's a coincidence. Is there any other setting that allows me to say 'Let other devices view my PCs on my home network' I might not know about besides just saying 'share this folder'?

Comment: See my edited answer for LAN Manager setting.